# What are the sections of a x86 linux binary?

Tags: assembly, x86, objdump

I want to learn reverse engineering so I was starting to try compiling simple (to start with) C programs and then reading the disassembly.

The following file

```
int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with `gcc` then disassembled with `objdump -d` ends up creating 172 lines of output. I don't understand why there is so much output.

What is the meaning of the different sections:

```
0000000000400370 <_init>:
0000000000400390 <__libc_start_main@plt-0x10>:
00000000004003a0 <__libc_start_main@plt>:
00000000004003b0 <__gmon_start__@plt>:
00000000004003c0 <_start>:
00000000004003f0 <deregister_tm_clones>:
0000000000400420 <register_tm_clones>:
0000000000400460 <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
0000000000400480 <frame_dummy>:
00000000004004ad <main>:
00000000004004c0 <__libc_csu_init>:
0000000000400530 <__libc_csu_fini>:
0000000000400534 <_fini>:
```

Of course I have been reading about the calling convention and opcodes so I can see how the  section corresponds to the C code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you're mixing up sections with functions.

What you have provided in your question are functions necessary to an ELF binary to execute. For example, the `_start` function is usually the *entry point* of a binary and it will probably call the `main` function at some point. You can get the address of the entry of a binary using `readelf -h` on the binary file you have.

About the output, though your program is "empty" it was still compiled & linked successfully - for that it is not erroneous - into an executable ELF. This document provides everything you need to know about how an ELF binary is structured & how to manipulate it : [ELF Format](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) (PDF).

Now if you want to retrieve section information in a binary file the `readelf` function can again help with that, you just have to call it with the `-S` and the target binary file (`readelf -S prog`).

Since you're just starting to learn, I recommend you checking the binutils (`readelf`, `objdump`, ...) and their related documentation and start playing with simple programs before moving to crackmes and more advanced or obfuscated binary files.

Answer (score 3):

Those are not sections, those are different functions in your binary. These are called in various times during process' lifetime.

What you are interested in is function `main`. `objdump -d` disassembles the whole binary, but if you are trying to understand what's going on in `main` only, at this point , you don't have to look at the rest of those.

When you use `gcc` to compile a binary into an executable, linker is called.
If you don't want the linker to be called, to generate an object file, use `gcc -c`. Here's the result of `objdump -d test.o`:

```
$ objdump -d test.o 

test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
   9:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   a:   c3                      retq
```

Here, since the code isn't linked , you only see your function.